# Stream huge html data from node server inside div contenteditable?

Tags: html, node.js, http, stream

I am converting docx file to html using mammoth.js in node server and fetching the html generated to place inside div contenteditable . However the html output is very large sometimes reaching 4-5 MB due to images and causes a delay in the frontend, What is the best way to handle this delay problem and stream html data from backend ?

Comment: Is the actual problem sending large data over an unstable connection? or is the backend timing out when generating this html?

Comment: Backend is actually timing out when I am getting the html and sometimes it takes long time to receive the html , how do I fix this error